# Можно ли использовать список с тем же именем, что и строка?

Tags: python

Код отрабатывает без ошибок, просто хочу уточнить.
На вход поступает строка из чисел, разделенных пробелами.

```
numbers = input()
numbers = numbers.split()
print(numbers)
```

Comment: да, можно. главное, сами не запутайтесь потом.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Некоторые линтеры считают это некрасивым и ругаются, когда в одну и ту же переменную пихают объекты разных типов (но это дело вкуса, технически никто не запрещает)

Comment: Интересно, что в языке Rust, при том что он строго типизирован, прямо разрешено такое: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477630/4752653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Питон - язык без строгой типизации, поэтому в одной и той же переменной можно держать по очереди всё, что угодно - строку, число, список и даже ссылку на функцию, например.

Но нужно помнить, что такой подход сильно затрудняет чтение кода, поэтому обычно для разных сущностей программистами используются разные переменные и, желательно, "с говорящими названиями".

В конкретно вашем случае более понятно для читающего код было бы назвать результат `input`-а например `input_numbers` либо `numbers_string`, чтобы было понятно, что это не список чисел, как в `numbers`, а строка - результат пользовательского ввода.

И ещё. Беспокоиться, что лишние переменные захламляют память программы, обычно не нужно. Если вы пишете код в виде функций, то при выходе из функции локальные переменные перестают быть действующими, и если памяти программе вдруг будет не хватать в какой-то момент, то сработает сборщик мусора и вернёт память, использовавшуюся этими переменными, в общий доступ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, в python нету жесткой типизации, одну перемену переменную можно переназначить на совсем другое, к примеру с int на str, или даже list на dict.

```
a = 15
print(a)
a = 'Hello wrold'
print(a)
a = ["1",1,1.1]
print(a)
a = {1:"yes"}
print(a)
```

Главное чтобы не путались в названиях переменных и их содержимым :)

Comment: Вот как у вас в примере точно лучше не делать.

Comment: Согласен, заранее что предполагалось хранить в переменной, должно и дальше храниться, и называться соответственно. Но не кто не мешает переопределять их